# Compare a multi-select picklist with another picklist in a Validation Rule

Tags: validation-rule

There is a picklist field on account as OKOCE_Country__c and on user object we have QIDC__OK_Available_Countries_ims__c multiplist field.
I want a validation rule to check is QIDC__OK_Available_Countries_ims__c not contains in OKOCE_Country__c then throw error on createion of account.
But we cant use this directly in validation rule as i used below rule but its not working and throws error. so how can we do this? By avoiding apex.

```
AND(
    NOT(
        Contains($User.QIDC__OK_Available_Countries_ims__c, TEXT(OKOCE_Country__c)
    )
),
OR(
    RecordType.Name = 'MP (Medical Professional)',
    RecordType.Name = 'Pharmacy',
    RecordType.Name = 'Institution'
)
)
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Field QIDC__OK_Available_Countries_ims__c is a multi-select picklist field. Multi-select picklist fields are only supported in certain functions

Comment: Since QIDC__OK_Available_Countries_ims__c is multipicklist so this cant be directly used in validation rule.
I tried to use a formula field(Text) on user and populate it with QIDC__OK_Available_Countries_ims__c .So that  could be used in validation rule But this approach also didn’t work.
The last approach was to create a new text field on user obj and populate it with values of QIDC__OK_Available_Countries_ims__c via Flows but in this also was facing same issue.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you have to go down the 'Apex' way - Use a before insert trigger and add custom error: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm

Answer (score 1):

The CONTAINS function in Salesforce is used to check if a specific value or substring exists within a target string.
Try the INCLUDES function instead. The INCLUDES function is specifically designed to work with multi-select picklist fields and checks if a specified value is present within the picklist selection.